# Hierarchical list based on two different properties of same List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of 'quests' with a quest that is 'granted' when one 'ends'. The quests are not stored in sequential order so I'm attempting to find two things.

```
class quests
{
    public string questGrantID { get; set; }
    public string questEndID { get; set; }
}
```

Example

```
+--------------+--------------+
| grants       | ends         |
+--------------+--------------+
| quest234     | quest567     |
| quest987     | quest234     |
| quest654     | quest987     |
+--------------+--------------+
```

**Parent Quests**: In this example I would know the 'Parent' quest is ***quest567*** because the parent is found under questEndID but not under questGrantID.

**Children Quests**: In this example, after ***quest567*** is completed, the user is granted ***quest234***. When quest ***quest234*** ends, ***quest987*** is granted and so on.

I don't know where to start, i've looked up example of joining two separate list, not the same. I assume this will be two different functions, one to find the parents and the other finding the children. From there i will create a new list.

Example

```
+--------------+--------------+
| order        | quest        |
+--------------+--------------+
| 1            | quest567     |
| 2            | quest234     |
| 3            | quest987     |
| 4            | quest654     |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the parent quests is easy, simply get a list of IDs not in any Grant.

Using a convenient extension method:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new HashSet<T>(source);
```

You can gather all the GrantIDs and find the EndIDs that aren't there:

```
var grants = questsList.Select(q => q.questGrantID).ToHashSet();
var parents = questsList.Select(q => q.questEndID).Where(q => !grants.Contains(q));
```

Now since your chain is recursive, you need a loop to follow the chain. Write another extension method to produce the quest chain from a starting point:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> questChain(this List<quests> allQuests, string curQuestID) {
    yield return curQuestID;

    var nextQuest = allQuests.ToDictionary(q => q.questEndID, q => q.questGrantID);

    for (; nextQuest.TryGetValue(curQuestID, out var nextQuestID); curQuestID = nextQuestID)
        yield return nextQuestID;
}
```

Now you can call that on all the parents to get all the chains:

```
var questChains = parents.Select(pq => questsList.questChain(pq));
```

Now if you really want the order,quest pair, you can number each chain:

```
var orderedQuests = questChains.Select(qc => qc.Select((quest, i) => new { order = i+1, quest } ));
```

If you want the numbering to be continuous across the chains, you will need to track it outside the query:

```
var curOrder = 1;
var orderedQuestsContinuous = questChains.Select(qc => qc.Select(quest => new { order = curOrder++, quest }));
```